# JSNI callback to GWT function from Foundation - not being fired

Tags: gwt, zurb-foundation, jsni

I'm again battling an issue with JSNI callbacks (see my posting history). I'm building a wrapper to Foundation Joyride (a tour). The tour runs correctly, but the "postRideCallback" (which is invoked after the tour is finished) does not fire. If I call the tour from the console with (close to) the same syntax, the callback does fire.

Here's what works, from the console:

```
$(document).foundation( 
    { joyride : 
        { post_ride_callback : function() 
            { window.alert('hello world'); } 
    } 
}).foundation('joyride', 'start')
```

Here's the relevant GWT code; calling start() runs the tour, but the callback never is invoked.

```
public void start() {
    __native_start(endTour(this), anotherFunction(this));
}

public native static void __native_start(JavaScriptObject endTour, JavaScriptObject  
anotherFunction) /*-{
    anotherFunction(); // this runs

    $wnd.$($doc).foundation(
        { joyride :
            { postRideCallback: function() // this does not run
                { 
                  anotherFunction(); 
                  endTour(); 
                }
            }
        }
    ).foundation('joyride', 'start');
}-*/;

public static native JavaScriptObject endTour(Tour tour) /*-{
    return tour == null ? null : $entry(function() {
        tour.@io.myapp.client.ui.widgets.foundation.Tour::tourHasEnded()()
    });
}-*/;

public static native JavaScriptObject anotherFunction(Tour tour) /*-{
    return tour == null ? null : $entry(function() {
        tour.@io.myapp.client.ui.widgets.foundation.Tour::callbackSuccess()()
    });
}-*/;

public void callbackSuccess() {
    Window.alert("hello yes");
}
```

EDIT - just to be clear here:

a) Note that the first call to anotherFunction() works. It pops up an alert with "hello yes" prior to running the tour.
b) If I replace the body of the postStepCallback function with either `window.alert('hello world');` or `$wnd.alert('hello world')`, nothing happens. So I don't believe this has anything to do with the GWT references per se (although I see they seem to be wrong).

EDIT2 - ok, made some modifications per Tomasz (and removed $entry boilerplate as an experiment). New behaviour - stacktrace in dev mode console (after code):

```
public void start() {
    __native_start(endTour(this), anotherFunction(this));
}

public native static void __native_start(JavaScriptObject endTour, JavaScriptObject         anotherFunction) /*-{
    anotherFunction();

    $wnd.$($doc).foundation(
        { joyride :
            { postRideCallback: function() { endTour(); } }
        }
    ).foundation('joyride', 'start');
}-*/;

public static native JavaScriptObject endTour(Tour tour) /*-{
    return tour.@io.myapp.client.ui.widgets.foundation.Tour::tourHasEnded();
}-*/;

public static native JavaScriptObject anotherFunction(Tour tour) /*-{
    return tour.@io.myapp.client.ui.widgets.foundation.Tour::callbackSuccess();
}-*/;

public void tourHasEnded() {
    Window.alert("hello double");
}

public void callbackSuccess() {
    Window.alert("hello yes");
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (String) : Invoking an instance method on a null instance   
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)    
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)     
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)     
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)  
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.createJavaScriptException(ModuleSpace.java:80)  
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.createJavaScriptException(ModuleSpace.java:64)  
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:60)   
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)    
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)    
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)    
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)    
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)  
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:299)  
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)    
at io.myapp.client.ui.widgets.foundation.Tour.__native_start(Tour.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer: I was using the old (Foundation 4) camel case rather than underscore seperated option name in the GWT code. In the console I'd figured out that underscore was correct late last night, but forgot about that when I tried this with GWT this morning. Ugh.